# How can I make a shared_ptr from an opaque pointer typedef? (or: how can I "unwrap" typedef?)

Tags: c++

If you have an opaque pointer typedef, is there a way to dynamically refer to the pointed-to type, say, for use in templates? For instance, say you have something like this:

```
struct Foo; // Forward declared struct
typedef Foo* FooPtr; // Opaque pointer
```

Because the smart pointer types are templates in terms of the pointer-to type, to define a `std::shared_ptr` of this, it seems that you have to say:

```
std::shared_ptr<struct Foo> theSharedPtr;
```

Is there any way to define such a pointer without "manually" unwrapping the opaque pointer typedef?  I feel like I must be missing something obvious here, but you might imagine something like these (note: these do not work):

```
std::shared_ptr<*FooPtr> theSharedPointer;
// or
std::shared_ptr<pointedto(FooPtr)> theSharedPointer;
```

I feel like this should be possible. Am I missing something? I feel like this is an impending forehead-smacking moment...

EDIT: Noodling around some more, it appears that, in the common case, `shared_ptr<T>` wants to take the `sizeof(T)`. You can get around this by providing a deleter to the constructor. I suspect this makes this a bit of an edge case, but it still seems like with all the type wrangling in C++, I should be able to "unwrap" a pointer type without doing so by hand.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In C++11:

```
#include <type_traits>

typedef std::shared_ptr< std::remove_pointer< FooPtr >::type > theSharedPtr;
```

In C++03 you can use `boost::remove_pointer` in the exact same way.

If you don't want to include boost, writing a `remove_pointer` metafunction is quite easy:

```
template<class T> struct remove_pointer;
template<class T> struct remove_pointer<T*> { typedef T type; };
```

Comment: Well considering you are using std::shared_ptr is obvious that you are in C++11... I'll leave the rest of my answer here anyway.

Comment: I like the completeness of the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, since you are already using C++11 features, you can do this with [*type traits*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types). Specifically by using [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer):

```
std::remove_pointer<Foo*>::type; // Foo
```

Of course you'll need to include the specific standard header which is:

```
#include <type_traits>
```

to use it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to define such a pointer without "manually" unwrapping the opaque pointer typedef?

```
#include <type_traits>
std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer<FooPtr>::type> theSharedPointer;
```

> it appears that, in the common case, `shared_ptr<T>` wants to take the `sizeof(T)`.

It (probably) doesn't need the size; but its initialisation needs to create a deleter, for which the type needs to be complete.